# Why the expected value need to vanishes?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

This question refers to the link https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/

The following is copied form the notes:"  It is mentioned that random variable $X$, $Y$, are independent if one has $Ef(X)g(Y)=0$ where $f,g:R->R$ are well-behaved functions (such as polynomials) such that all of $Ef(X),Eg(Y)$ vanishes. "

My question is what vanishes means? I assumed it means the terms $Ef(X),Eg(Y)$ goes to zero. But why should $Ef(X)$ or $Eg(Y)$ needs to go to zero? Independence means only their product needs to go to zero.

Comment: "all of $Ef(X),Eg(Y)$ vanishes" means that $E(f(X))=E(g(Y))=0$.

Comment: Quote: "My question is what vanishes means? I assumed it means the terms $Ef(X),Eg(Y)$ goes to zero". Note how my answer contradicts what you say (which is not very clear, granted).

Comment: I think the intended meaning is: $X,Y$ are independent if $Cov(f(X),g(Y))=0$ for a large enough set of functions $f,g$. (If for example $X,Y$ have all finite moments, then polynomials will suffice here.)

Answer (score 0):

The comment never said that independence of $X$ and $Y$ mean $Ef(X)$ and $Eg(Y)$ are zero or vanishes. The statement is considering a class of commutative random variable $X$ and $Y$ such that $Ef(X)$ and $Eg(Y)$ are zero; in that case $Ef(X)g(Y)$ is zero.